# Regex to match email id's in javascript?

Tags: regex

Lets say I have something like this:

- vin@text.com
- jay@text.com
- text@text.com

All these id's belong to @text.com, and I want to match just that, whether an id has a

> @text.com

or not

for example:

> vin@gmail.com is invalid

while

> vin@text.com is valid

but

> vin@text.com.com , vin@text.com@text.com are both invalid

there should not be any characters after @text.com but there can be as many as possible in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

So, text.com can be treated as required after `@` for your scenario.
Simple regex could be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@text.com+$
```

Please have a look if this works for you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Great! here is the small fiddle in case you need it. https://jsfiddle.net/gmall/0zdjp4Ly/